# How to call a web service (described by a wsdl) from java

Tags: java, web-services, soap

Knowing nothing of web services, I'm just trying to call some "isAlive" service that is described by a wsdl.

This seems to me like something that should take no more than 2-5 lines of code but I can't seem to find anything but huge long examples involving 3rd party packages etc.

Anyone has any ideas? If it is always suppose to be long maybe a good explanation as to why it has to be so complicated will also be appreciated.
I'm using Eclipse and the wsdl is SOAP.

Comment: Can you please provide the IDE you use?

Comment: Can you look at the wsdl, whether it's SOAP or any other protocol? I guess it's SOAP but just to make sure.

Comment: It is soap : xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding

and I'm using eclipse IDE

Answer (score 6):

JDK 6 comes with jax-ws, everything you need to develop a client for a web service.

I'm unable to find some simple enough examples to post , but start at  https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/

Edit: here's a simple example - a client for this web service: http://xmethods.com/ve2/ViewListing.po?key=427565

```
C:\temp> md generated
C:\temp>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17"\bin\wsimport -keep -d generated http://www50.brinkster.com/vbfacileinpt/np.asmx?wsdl
```

Create PrimeClient.java which look like:

```
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;
import com.microsoft.webservices.*; 
//the above namespace is from the generated code from the wsdl. 

public class PrimeClient {
 //Cant  get this to work.. @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation="http://www50.brinkster.com/vbfacileinpt/np.asmx?wsdl")
  static PrimeNumbers service;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    service = new PrimeNumbers();
      PrimeClient client = new PrimeClient();
      client.doTest(args);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void doTest(String[] args) {
    try {
      System.out.println("Retrieving the port from the following service: " + service);
      PrimeNumbersSoap pm = service.getPrimeNumbersSoap();
      System.out.println("Invoking the getPrimeNumbersSoap operation ");
      System.out.println(pm.getPrimeNumbers(100));
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Compile and run:

```
C:\temp>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17"\bin\javac -cp generated PrimeClient.java
C:\temp>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17"\bin\java -cp .;generated PrimeClient
Retrieving the port from the following service: com.microsoft.webservices.PrimeN
umbers@19b5393
Invoking the getPrimeNumbersSoap operation
1,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97
```

Comment: Are you certain that you don't simply call the class itself? I can see no network callup in your code? Does it work when you are offline too?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer The wdsl contains the network address and the generated code takes care of setting up the connection to that service. This obviously does not work if you are offline as the server will be unreachable

Comment: Both the links in the answer are dead.

Comment: The actual answer, which is supposed to be in the link, is unreachable due to a dead link.

Answer (score 4):

There are plugins for IDE's which generate the needed code to consume a web service for you.

After the plugin generates you the base methods you simply call a web service like that:

```
TransportServiceSoap service = new TransportServiceLocator().getTransportServiceSoap();
service.getCities();
```

Have a look at http://urbas.tk/index.php/2009/02/20/eclipse-plug-in-as-a-web-service-client/

Comment: Great link. Solved my problem instantly.

Comment: the urban.tk is down, broken link!

Answer (score 1):

[There are three ways to write a web service client](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC5.html)

1. Dynamic proxy
2. Dynamic invocation interface (DII)
3. Application client

**Example for Dynamic Proxy Client**

```
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.rpc.Service;

import javax.xml.rpc.JAXRPCException;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceFactory;

import dynamicproxy.HelloIF;

public class HelloClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String UrlString = "Your WSDL URL";  // 
            String nameSpaceUri = "urn:Foo";
            String serviceName = "MyHelloService";
            String portName = "HelloIFPort";

            System.out.println("UrlString = " + UrlString);
            URL helloWsdlUrl = new URL(UrlString);

            ServiceFactory serviceFactory =
                ServiceFactory.newInstance();

            Service helloService =
                serviceFactory.createService(helloWsdlUrl, 
                new QName(nameSpaceUri, serviceName));

            dynamicproxy.HelloIF myProxy = 
                (dynamicproxy.HelloIF) 
                helloService.getPort(
                new QName(nameSpaceUri, portName), 
                dynamicproxy.HelloIF.class); 

            System.out.println(myProxy.sayHello("Buzz"));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } 
}
```

[I hope , this would solve your question.](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC5.html)

Comment: eclipse cannot find these imports. what packages do I need to add to my build path?

Comment: All packages are come with JDK except "import dynamicproxy.HelloIF;", you could remove this package.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest I've found so far to use is the Idea IntelliJ wizard which - using Metro libraries - generate a very small code snippet which works fine with Java 6.

Comment: downvote?  Its true :)  Works fine with Java 6 without any extra libraries, that is.